# Parallax scrolling - stop element after while

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, parallax

I have problem with parallax scrolling element.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {

  var wScroll = $(this).scrollTop();

  $('.eboy').css({
    'transform': 'translate(0px, ' + wScroll / 12 + '%)'
  });


});
```

```css
.section1 {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  height: 800px;
  background-image: url("../images/head.png");
  size: auto 600px;
  position: top-center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.section1 img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.eboy {
  width: 900px;
  height: 300px;
  background-image: url("../images/eboy.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: bottom;
  position: absolute;
  margin-right: 50%;
  margin-top: 5%;
}

.eboy2 {
  width: 1100px;
  height: 300px;
  background-image: url("../images/eboy.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: bottom right;
  position: absolute;
  margin-right: 40%;
  margin-top: 5%;
  z-index: -100;
}

.section2 {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  height: 646px;
  background-image: url("../images/dobrodosli01.png");
  size: contain;
  position: top-center;
  z-index: -100;
}

.section2 img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.section3 {
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url("../images/kapija.png");
  z-index: 100;
}

.section3 img {
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="section1">
      <img src="images/Untitled-1.png" alt="" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="section2">
    <div class="eboy" id="eboy">
      <div class="eboy2">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

At the beginning, when I scroll, everything is okay: it moves `.eboy` and `.eboy2`. But after 1000px scrolling, I want to fix `#eboy2`, and continue moving only the background. So what I'd like to do is make `eBoy2` fixed in the middle of page, and around it should pass some elements. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(window).scroll(function(){

var wScroll = $(this).scrollTop();


if($(window).scrollTop() > 800){


    $(".eboy").css({"transform" :  "translateY(0px)"});
    $(".eboy").css("margin-top", wScroll-600+"px");

}
else{
     $('.eboy').css({
  'transform' : 'translate(0px, '+ wScroll /12 +'%)'
});
     $(".eboy").css("margin-top", "0px");
}

});
```

On the end this is solution for my problem, so maby this answer will help to someone.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite get what you are asking but it sounds like all you would need to do is use js to check the distance of scroll then set its position to fixed when at 1000px.

Check distance scrolled:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

    //if I scroll more than 1000px...
    if($(window).scrollTop() > 1000){

        //Then change the elements position to fixed:
        $("#element").css("position", "fixed"); 
    }
});
```

If you create a jsFiddle I would be happy to help

Comment: Probablly I need somethig as you post. Here is my fiddle 
https://jsfiddle.net/PoznanM/5v97bhj5/2/ 
But still it does not look same at my localhost and in JS fiddle. But if you can assist or help with this, thank you a lot. If not, thanks again.